# Browser limitation with maximum Page length

Tags: browser

We are managing html contents from datasource and directly write on the web pages using asp.net C#.

Here we are facing the problem :
On the page complete contents are not displaying but while we check the Page source and copy/paste it into a static html page all contents will be displayed.

Is there any limitation of browser related to maximum length of a web page.

I googled and found that the limit of a web page should be 10-30KB but in the same project we have pages with length upto 55 KB.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: The browser won't know the difference between a static html page and a page rendered by C# code on the server.  Are you sure you're not adding content to the page after it has been loaded?

Comment: Actually I have a method which convert all data into html and concatenate in strinbuilder one by one and the same method is called in Page_Load event.

Answer (score 25):

I've recently been benchmarking browser load times for very large text files.  Here are some data:

IE  --dies around 35 megs
Firefox --dies around 60 megs
Safari  --dies around 60 megs
Chrome  --dies around 50 megs

Again, this is simple browser load time of a basic (if large) English text files.  One strange note is that Firefox seems to handle close to 60 megs before becoming non-responsive, but it only puts 55.1 megs out on the viewport.  (However I can ctrl-a to get all 60 megs onto the clipboard.)
Naturally your mileage will vary, and this is all related to network latency, and we'll probably see vast differences if you're talking about downloading pictures etc.  This is just for a single very large file of english text.

Answer (score 1):

The limits (if they only exist) are higher than 50KB:

```
$ wget --quiet "http://www.cnn.com" -O- | wc -c
99863
```

I wouldn't believe there's any particular constant limit for page size. I would guess it rather depends on the memory size the web browser process can allocate.

Comment: 10 years later, that number is 10x the size
1133050

Answer (score 0):

Install firefox and firebug and try to examine any factors that could be affecting the source code.  Unless you are changing something odd in the C# it shouldn't be cut off.

Comment: Ben,
I have tried with Firefox and Chorme but the same result came out.

Comment: use the firebug extension to examine the live html