# ASP.Net ListItem Value Property Max length

Tags: asp.net, properties, listitem

Seems like a pretty straightforward question, but I can't find it anywhere.
Does anyone know the max length the value of a ListItem can be?

I am sure it is more than I will ever need for what I am doing, but just want to be sure.

Comment: What is the maximum size of a html page? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12629931/284240

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's theroretically unlimited. So it's just limited by your memory or the browsers capability.

- [Is there a limit to the length of HTML attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496096/is-there-a-limit-to-the-length-of-html-attributes?lq=1)
- [Browser limitation with maximum Page length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076622/browser-limitation-with-maximum-page-length/12629931#12629931)

On the server side it can be as long as a string in general. That is `int.MaxValue` chars. But you'll get problems on client side earlier.

- [What is the maximum possible length of a .NET string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140468/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-net-string)