# IE failed to generate reports

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, reporting-services, report, reportviewer

One of our client is trying to generate reports with lots of sub reports, its a single page report. If they generate it for 2-3 years it works for all browsers, but when they generate it for 5 years. Report works fine in chrome and firefox but IE will not be able to load reports and show IE window "Internet explorer cannot load page".

There is no errors in eventlog or in IE console. Even Fiddler does not give any information why IE could not able to load reports. It says response 200.

Reports are generated successfully, as I can see that in log.

I am not sure why this is happening with IE(8,9,10). Please check images below
[image]
[image]
[image]
Thanks

Comment: Try turning off HTTP 1.1 and clear the cache.

Comment: I'm not sure if it could be a known issue for IE browsers. Check if this post helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076622/browser-limitation-with-maximum-page-length

Comment: Yes it can be browser limitation as I can see in fiddler after 35kb it just show this error message. But what can be work around for this issue.

Comment: Convert it to pdf :) and download the pdf

Comment: That is not an option I have. I need to figure root of this cause first why its not working for IE.

Comment: any updates on this bug?

Comment: There really is no way to debug this using the available info. Chances are that there is a particular rendering bug in IE that is triggered by your markup.

If you're able to save the generated page and make it available, we might be able to figure out what's happening.

Comment: how long does it take to get the response? 11.8s? what about in Chrome and Mozilla?

Comment: is the request async?

Comment: Request is async, it fails after 11.8 seconds. Reports have approximately 5-6MB data, but IE will after after 3.5MB.

Answer (score 2):

This could be due to the memory management problem in Internet Explorer, as you are fetching the 5 year data. 
There is a work around for the memory problem.

->Go IIS
->Open your reporting Website
->Check which application pool its using
->Right click on that and recycle it.
->Then try generating the report.

Not sure if it resolves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a very similar issue recently - it started a few months ago, across multiple unchanged reports, and seemed to be triggered by hard or soft Page Breaks (I found that out from a lengthy process of elimination).

That scenario was SQL Server Reporting Services 2012 SP1, via the Native/Report Manager portal.

Does your report render with page breaks?

My solution was to set the Report / InteractiveSize / Height to 1000cm.  Then for each hard page break, I disabled it for browser rendering by setting the Page Break / Disable property using this expression:

`=Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive`

The result is a little untidy in the browser, but renders with page breaks in other formats (PDF, Word, Excel).  Importantly it stopped the browser freezing in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I have moved away from the report display control. It provides inconsistent display on different platforms (al least it did in 2013 when I did the lions share of converting a project).

Instead I render to PDF (Word or Excel) at the server and use an embed tag to display the content to the user. You are guaranteed to know what it looks like on the user screen that way. A level of caching is possible and its a lot easier to work with.