# Large HTML table to local database

Tags: html, json, database

When run with big datasets, my program produces large HTML files (i.e. sometimes in the range of 200mb). *(These result files would only be viewed locally and not via the internet)*.

BUT browsers are unable to open large files (see this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12629931?noredirect=1)) - i.e. the browser simply crashes before loading the full file.

This results file is literally just a table (smaller version seen [here](http://wurmlab.github.io/tools/genevalidator/exemplar_data/protein_input/)) that can be sorted. These large files sometimes have more than 30,000 rows...

I would use [Tablesorter with the Pager plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html), but the actual HTML file size is not reduced despite the table being split into pages. So this wouldn't solve the problem...

Thus I was planning on simply storing the table as a Json and then create smaller (paginated) tables via Javascript. I would also try to implement sorting using JS.

I have a feeling that there is probably a better way to do this (Js/Jquery will probably be to slow to sort 30,000+ rows of data etc.).

So are there any existing frameworks that I can use here?

Comment: Personally I would be leery of adding / relying on a framework... it took some time to run and complete (with jquery / javascript), but I had a similar issue with a recent project and I decided to write some javascript that would parse the html source and then use ajax to post to write to database record for each data element I wanted to store .  I also thought about a flat json file but didnt like the idea of such a large flat file and knew that ultimately the mysql database would be really flexible and let me sleep well at night.

Comment: You source file is well formatted, and it can be easily converted from HTML to shorter version (like in JSON format) with about 50% of original size, plus some elements can be removed (like <button> or repeating tags and information. I can write a Node.js converter for source file and help to write sorting procedures on the client if you contact me agershun at gmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer you are seeking is actually to **not** do what you are attempting.

Displaying 200mb of pretty much anything in the browser is likely not going to be useful to the end user - even if it does load, scrolling and re-painting will make it painful to use.

I'd recommend either a pre-filter that lets/forces the user filter down the results to a more meaningful data set... and/or cap the results to 50/100/250? with the ability to page through the remaining.

For the scenarios where the user really needs all the data (or the client insists ;-) **I'd recommend an option to download the data in CSV or a similar format** that they can import into their favorite text editor/spreadsheet (or even database) application.