# What is better for my task list or dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, web-applications

```
Months    X       Y       Z
June      a       b       c
July            
August
Sept
Oct 
Total   Sum(x)  Sum(y)  Sum(z)
```

I want this table in my webapp. a,b and c are provided and rest of the values are calculated from them. What should I use here list or dictionary.
Using list I would pass different lists for X Y and Z and sum that using sum value.
Ques 1->Is it ok to initialize a long list even when all the values have to be calculated from a,b and c?
Ques 2->If not what is a better method to do this?

Comment: Why do you think you should initialize a long list instead of adding to it as you go?

Comment: is it ok to process and add values to list in template? actually I thought calculations should be avoided in template.

Answer (score 0):

Question #1) How long is the long list?  The maximum size of a python list on a 32-bit machine is 536,870,912 according to this post...  [How Big can a Python Array Get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855191/how-big-can-a-python-array-get)

However I would think the first bottleneck you'll going to hit is actually getting that data to the browser.  Here's discussion on size limits with regards to various browsers...
[Browser limitation with maximum Page length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076622/browser-limitation-with-maximum-page-length)

Question# 2) If it's ultimately going out to a web app JSON format is going to be easier to work on with most front end frameworks.

Comment: maximum length can be around 84 which is rarest of rarest case